# How to handle data between two function call one after other

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, function, exception

I need to use two database function one in which i need to delete comment and after that second function called  which decreases the score of user .

Problem :
If exception occurs in second function score will not be deducted but comment was deleted .

I m trying store action of first function in class object  and if exception occurs in second , reverse action will be taken place to rewrite it in database . Is there any other approach possible to do this please suggest me .
thanks in advance

Comment: combine to one function to avoid extra handling?

Comment: In one function if  exception occurs after execution of first query than....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have both database calls within the scope of the same transaction.  Thus if you get an exception, all will be rolled back.

It depends on how you access the database but it could be something like this:

```
using (var Conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
{
    SqlTransaction trans = null;
    try
    {
        Conn.Open();
        trans = Conn.BeginTransaction();

        using (SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand(ComText, Conn, trans))
        {
                    // delete comment
                    // update score
         }
         trans.Commit();
      }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        if (trans != null) trans.Rollback();
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: updated answer, kept it to more clear example, but there are several good approaches to this, the one detailed is easy to follow but there is room for improvement, depends on your requirement but should point you in right direction

Answer (score 1):

If both functions should be writen or neighter one of them you need to put a transaction around both functions.

If you commit the transaction the comment and decrease score will be saved in the database, if you have a exception you can do a rollback and nothing happens in your database.